# Genymotion versions differ

Tags: android, installation, genymotion

Okay! I've just started to learn some basic Android programming.

To my frustration my computer was not quick enough to emulate the apps in a satisfying matter. Therefore I tried to install `Genymotion`, but my frustration didn't end there.

I have a fresh installation of `Genymotion` and install virtual devices trough their wizard, but get an error that says that there is a differ in versions between `Genymotion` and the `virutal device`. What should I do?

I just installed the latest version of Genymotion (Version 2.2.0).

Then I try to install a virtual device (notice the version 2.2.0)

http://giggle.se/stack/genymotion_device_version.PNG

After installning the device i run it and the following error occurs:

http://giggle.se/stack/genymotion.PNG

Any ideas?

Comment: I've just posted a solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846324/android-genymotion-version-and-virtual-device-version-do-not-match/23909879#23909879

Answer (score 1):

From my observations Genymotion always fetches the latest virtual guests version matching to latest `Genymotion` version. Todays downloaded virtual guests match genymotion 2.2.0.

I had the version missmatch on my 2.1.1 guests while running `Genymotion` 2.2.0, it recommended to use the latest virtual guests.

I must admit it is pretty odd that your `Genymotion` fetches old versions. Though i had bad luck in updating to

*Genymotion 2.2.0: new virtual guests are instable, old virtual guests become instable too, even downgrade to 2.1.1 did not fix stability issues with 2.1.1 guests.*

I would suggest to clean the *`clear the cache in Genymotion (Settings/Misc/Clear cache)`*, so all logs and temporary files get deleted and give it another try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried to erase the cache, but there is no change. I might try to re-install everything to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So I **cleared** *cache in Genymotion(Settings/Misc/Clear cache)*, **reinstall Genymotion** and Restart my Laptop. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

This happened on one of my Macs. Clearing the cache didn't help. Neither did reinstalling Genymotion. However I found a solution (I assume some sort of similar procedure applies to Windows PCs):

proceed to a fresh install of Genymotion 2.2.0 on another Mac (let's call it: "source"). Add a new device (for instance "Google Nexus 7 2013"). The correct 2.2.0 virtual device will be downloaded from the Genymotion Cloud. Launch the virtual machine once, then close it.

on the "source" Mac, open the Finder and use the "Go to folder" menu to browse to the /Users/[YourUserID]/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed folder. Locate the folder corresponding to your newly installed virtual device (i.e. "Google Nexus 7 2013 - 4.4.2 - API 19 - 1200x1920" in our example) and copy it to the exact same location onto your "target" Mac (assuming there's no existing folder with this name)

on your "source" Mac, browse to the /Users/[YourUserID]/Library folder (Alt key + "Go to folder" menu in the Finder). Go to the VirtualBox folder and open the VirtualBox.xml file with TextEdit. Locate the line that matches your newly installed virtual device in the section; add this line to section of the VirtualBox.xml file of your "target" Mac (located in the same folder).

That's it! Start Genymotion on your "target" Mac and launch your new virtual device. No more "genymotion version and virtual device version do not match" warning.